# I can't insert into MsAccess database

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

i have the following UI
[image]

but then, i can't insert any data to the `ms access database`. the first row was generated manually through `ms access database`

i don't know what's the matter with my code, it seems they're all doing just fine

```
private void doSimpan(String idnya, String namanya,String alamatnya,String teleponnya,String emailnya,String passwordnya,String rolesnya)    {   
    try {
        String query = "INSERT INTO MsEmployee (EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeAddress, EmployeePhone, EmployeeEmail, EmployeePassword, EmployeeRole)VALUES ('"+idnya+"','"+namanya+"','"+alamatnya+"','"+teleponnya+"','"+emailnya+"','"+passwordnya+"','"+rolesnya+"')";
        connect.executeQuery(query);
        fillTable();
        cmd.printSuccess("Master Employee", namanya+" saved successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

here is the `execQuery` method

```
    private statement st;
public void executeQuery(String query)
    {
        try {
            st.executeUpdate(query);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " +ex);
        }
    }
```

here is my `printAsk()` method

```
public Boolean printAsk(String title, String text)
{
    if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, text, title, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

here is my `isValid()` method

```
private Boolean isValid(String name,String address,String phone,String email,String password)    {
    if(name.equals("") || address.equals("") || phone.equals("") || email.equals("") || password.equals(""))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(val.isNumeric(phone) || !email.contains("@") && !email.endsWith(".com"))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here is the code on my `save button`

```
   //save
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String idnya = jTextField1.getText();
    String namanya = jTextField2.getText();
    String alamatnya = jTextArea1.getText();
    String teleponnya = jTextField3.getText();
    String emailnya  = jTextField4.getText();
    String passwordnya = new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword());
    String rolesnya = jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(status==1) //to insert
    {

        if(isValid(namanya, idnya, teleponnya, emailnya, passwordnya))
        {
            if(cmd.printAsk("Master Employee", namanya+" will be entered, continue ?"))
            {
                doSimpan(idnya, namanya, alamatnya, teleponnya, emailnya, passwordnya, rolesnya);
                fillTable();
                defaultControl(false,false);
                crudButton(true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.printFail("Master Employee", "all field must be filled");
        }
    }
    else if (status==2)//to update
    {            

    }

}
```

where do i go wrong ? 
i got "nencor saved successfully" but then, i can't find any employee named `nencor` on the ms access database

my `Connect` constructor

```
 public Connect() {
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=TIFProject.mdb");
        st = con.createStatement(1004, 1008);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Database Error" + ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) use a real database, the bridge driver's unsupported and has been for going on a decade. 2) check your autocommit settings, common cause of such problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this in your program.

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL ,"",""); //databaseURL is url for your db
st=connection.createStatement();
```

Error occurred because you didn't mention and initialize variables needed for database interaction.Write above three lines in `execQuery`method and its done.

Comment: i made it on `Connect` class

Comment: wrong, depending on how it's set up it's quite possible to use the jdbc-odbc bridge junk without credentials.

Comment: @jwenting i have updated the thread. tell me if you need more information. i don't know what to do since the program is not returning any error message

Comment: @Cignitor you are defining statement in `connect()` constructor and again intializing it in `execQuery`.?? Remove this statement `private statement st;` which is before `execQuery` method.

Comment: @VimalBera i have commented on that line, and stil, that line does no effect. i am still wondering what goes wrong in my code . . .

Answer (score 0):

```
private statement st;
public void executeQuery(String query)
    {
        try {
            st.executeUpdate(query);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " +ex);
        }
    }
```

Have you initialize the variable 'st'

Comment: what is initialize ? does it like `private statement st = null` ?